# drop down menu hidden behind the frame

Tags: html, css, menu, frame

I have a website which is build using frames. In topFrame.php, I have a menu which loads drop down sub menu. And in main frame, there is the content of the website. The problem is, when topFrame loads the submenu, it is hidden behind the mainFrame. is there any way to stop this? It will be very time consuming for me to make the whole website frameless

Comment: Can you share some codes in jsfiddle? Maybe it can be fixed width z-index

Comment: @Chanckjh i am unable to download my file. http://ahbg.qwpcorp.com/remem/topFrame_new.php you can see my example

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the menu cannot be made visible outside the frame.
Its a good idea to get rid of the frames. But if it is time consuming, on suggestion is to go for a menu which looks like **[this](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample4)** (a tabbed submenu).

It will not go beyond the frame if you have limited set of menu items.
Hope it helps!